# Subtract each column

Tags: r

I have the following question:

How can I manage to subtract each column from each other? As an example: I have 200 columns and I want to subtract column 1 from all the other columns, after that column 2 from all the other columns, column 3 and so on. With the code below I am only able to subtract column 1 from each other f_minus(df[,1], df[,i]).

What do I have to do that the 1 in df[,1] changes automatically to 2, 3 , 4 , 5 until the last column?

An example:

```
After substraction from column 1 the result should looks like:
A01 <- c(0, 0)
A02 <- c(2, 3)
A03 <- c(3, 4)
A04 <- c(6, 6)
A05 <- c(0, NA)
 
After substraction from column 2 the result should looks like:
A01 <- c(-2, -3)
A02 <- c(0, 0)
A03 <- c(1, 1)
A04 <- c(4, 3)
A05 <- c(-2, NA)

etc.

Initial situation

A01 <- c(1, 2)
A02 <- c(3, 5)
A03 <- c(4, 6)
A04 <- c(7, 8)
A05 <- c(1, NA)

df <-  data.frame(A01, A02, A03, A04, A05, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df



# Define the function
f_minus <- function(first_col, other_col) {
  
  other_col - first_col
  
}

df_output <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=ncol(df), nrow=nrow(df))) 

for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  
  df_output[,i] <- f_minus(df[,1], df[,i])
  
}

df_output
```

Thank you for your help :) I really appreciate that.
If you have further question just let me know!

Selina1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lapply` which works column-wise. Each column in the dataframe is subtracted from the entire dataframe.

```
result <- lapply(df, function(x) df - x)
result

#$A01
#  A01 A02 A03 A04 A05
#1   0   2   3   6   0
#2   0   3   4   6  NA

#$A02
#  A01 A02 A03 A04 A05
#1  -2   0   1   4  -2
#2  -3   0   1   3  NA

#$A03
#  A01 A02 A03 A04 A05
#1  -3  -1   0   3  -3
#2  -4  -1   0   2  NA

#$A04
#  A01 A02 A03 A04 A05
#1  -6  -4  -3   0  -6
#2  -6  -3  -2   0  NA

#$A05
#  A01 A02 A03 A04 A05
#1   0   2   3   6   0
#2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

`lapply` is like a `for` loop where the first iteration is all the values of column 1, second iteration would be all the values of column 2 and so on.

Similar to `lapply` you can also use `purrr::map` -

```
result <- purrr::map(df, ~df - .x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But could you explain me why this works?

Comment: It is similar to for loop. I have edited the answer to include some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! and what would I have to do so that in the next run, after column 1 has been subtracted from all other columns 2, column 2 is not subtracted from column 1, and so on. ?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
lapply(df, \(x) df - x)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! and what would I have to do so that in the next run, after column 1 has been subtracted from all other columns 2, column 2 is not subtracted from column 1, and so on. ?